# Definition of $\hat{G_1}\times \hat{G_2}$ where $G_1,G_2$ are abelian groups and $\hat{G}$ is the dual of $G$

Tags: topological-groups, characters

The question is in the title. I want to know what happens to $(\chi_G,\chi_H)\in\hat{G}\times \hat{H}$. Are they just passively sitting there as a pair or they give something when applied on $(g,h)$?

My hunch is $(\chi_G,\chi_H)(g,h)=\chi_G(g)\chi_H(h)$ but is this the definition? I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have found out is that there is a canonical map
$$m : \hat{G}_1 \times \hat{G}_2 \to \widehat{G_1 \times G_2}$$
which maps $(\phi,\psi)$ to the mapping $m(\phi,\psi) : (g,h) \mapsto \phi(g) \psi(h)$. But by itself, $(\phi,\psi)$ cannot act on $(g,h)$, you have to apply this $m$ first. The map $m$ is a bijection, so it's reasonable to view $(\phi,\psi)$ as an element of the dual of $G_1 \times G_2$ anyway.

Comment: If $\chi \in \widehat{G_1 \times G_2}$ then $\phi(g)= \chi(g,0)$ and $\psi(h)=\chi(0,h)$ are in $\hat{G_1}$ respectively $\hat{G_2}$ and $$\chi=m(\phi, \psi)$$ The mapping is always surjective....

Comment: @N.S. You're right... That's what I get for trying to veer of my usual areas of math :) I was thinking about maps like $V^* \otimes W^* \to (V \otimes W)^*$ which are not always isomorphisms (when $V$, $W$ are finite dimensional), but of cours the situation is different here.